# Добавить кнопку на виджет Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Нужна функция добавления кнопки на виджет

```
void func(QWidget *widg){
  QPushButton butt(widg);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  QWidget widg;
  func(&widg);
  widg.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

Не добавляет

Comment: Конечно не добавляет! Также если вы будете пихать куб в круглое отверстие диаметром меньше диагонали грани куба, то оно тоже не пролезет, так как не предназначено для этого. Нужна функция - я думаю вам не функция нужна, а познакомиться с с++ для начала, узнать что такое классы и наследование и чем отличается куча то стэка, а потом уже заниматься qt

Comment: Как знание кучи и стека решит эту проблему?

Comment: По меньшей мере это избавит вас от таких вот вопросов.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch: тут дело не в куче и с стеке, а в том что ТС не знает/понимает что происходит после выхода из области определенной им функции.

Comment: @LLENN ТС много чего не знает, но то, что происходит после выхода из функции, как раз таки, связано со стэком и кучей (в данном случае только со стэком). Но и это не основная проблема, а в том, что дабавление кнопки происходит вообще не так. Вообщем это классический пример обезьяны с пишущей машинкой, которая случайным образом нажимает клавиши - в масштабах вселенной может получиться, что она напишет что-то действительно хорошее, но это не тот случай.

Comment: QPushButton *butt = new QPushButton(widg); // дабы не мучить человека.

Comment: @FrozenM проблема в том, что вы ему этим никак не помогли, даже скорее запутали. Вы сами то знаете ответ на вопрос?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch ну, разумеется, не знаю. Пишу просто наугад. Вы утверждаете, что кнопка на виджет так не добавится? Человек потыкается и станет правильно добавлять. И показывать, если надо. И в нужное место поставит. А потом и в лэйаут (не знаю что это, но поумничаю) положит.

Comment: @FrozenM серьезно... Ну проверьте сами, скиньте скрин мы вместе проверим так ли это)))

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch Вы сами проверьте. И удивитесь.

Comment: @FrozenM нет, я настаиваю. Хочу посмотреть на это. Или вы думаете я вас просто так попросил скинуть скрин? Но раз вы отказываетесь, скажу сразу: а что дальше? Ну добавили вы кнопку в виджет - без надписи, функционала, не выровненую и абсолютно бесполезную. Или я, по-вашему, просто так в первом посте указал классы и наследование (помимо кучи и стэка)?

Answer (score 0):

Поясню — проблема в том, что у Вас в функции Ваша кнопка создается в стэке. И при выходе из функции она удаляется.

Одно из простейших решений (и, имхо, наиболее правильное) — создавать в куче. Как в примере ниже. Ну и, естественно, почитайте умные книжки. Проще будет. Проще, чем все пытаться решить опытным путем.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

void func(QWidget *widg){
QPushButton *butt = new QPushButton(widg);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  QWidget widg;
  func(&widg);
  widg.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

[image: Видна маленькая синенькая кнопочка]

Comment: а, так вы все-таки сделали. Ну напишу тогда это и сдесь: а что делать с этой кнопкой дальше? Как поменять местоположение, добавить надпись, связать ее с хоть чем-нибудь? Не знаю, может вы направо и налево создаете такие кнопки, но я не понимаю как вы их используете.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch Всё-всё... Вы победили ;) Спокойной ночи ;)